# marklogic datahub quickstart installtion problem[close]

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

Now I am trying to install MarkLogic Datahub into marklogic acording to bellow guide.

https://marklogic.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/project/quickstart/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJu53.png)

After inputting my ID and PW in above form, it should've been connected to next screen but it couldn't.

It seems my ID and PW be collect, because other ID and PW was entered then invlaid pw meesage shown.

So I think my ID and PW is right.

Is there any networking problem?
Or do you have any hit??

`````````````````````````````
11:30:12.341 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for se                                                               rvlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unsupported auth scheme: [Basic realm=public]
        at com.burgstaller.okhttp.digest.DigestAuthenticator.findDigestHeader(DigestAuthenticator.java:19                                                               8)
        at com.burgstaller.okhttp.digest.DigestAuthenticator.authenticate(DigestAuthenticator.java:163)
        at com.burgstaller.okhttp.CachingAuthenticatorDecorator.authenticate(CachingAuthenticatorDecorato                                                               r.java:30)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.followUpRequest(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.
````````````````````````````

```````````````

2019-06-25 11:30:12.199  INFO 23752 --- [io-8080-exec-10] com.marklogic.hub.impl.DataHubImpl       :
Checking MarkLogic Installation:
        AppServers:
                Staging: MISSING
                Final:   MISSING
                Jobs:     MISSING
        Databases:
                Staging: MISSING
                Final:   MISSING
                Jobs:     MISSING
        Databases Indexes:
                Staging Triples Index : MISSING
                Staging Collection Lexicon : MISSING
                Final Triples Index : MISSING
                Final Collection Lexicon : MISSING
        Forests
                Staging: MISSING
                Final:   MISSING
                Jobs:     MISSING
        Core Hub Databases:
                Modules: MISSING
                Staging Schemas: MISSING
                Staging Triggers: MISSING


OVERALL RESULT: NOT INSTALLED
`````````````````````````````

I'll be appreciated if you help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you start the MarkLogic service? You could check by looking if http://localhost:8001/ is responding..

Comment: Yes, I did.

 Actually, MarkLogic is running on a server and I am connecting to it from browser hitting the IP address. I found host:8001 working and even be able to connect datahub console on host:8080. 

But even after hitting my ID and PW, which seems to be correct, I can not move forward to installation process.

Comment: Here's server network configuration. If you have any hint, would you tell me?


[opc@wbf-poc-marklogic ~]$ sudo firewall-cmd --info-service=MarkLogic
MarkLogic
  ports: 7997/tcp 7998/tcp 7999/tcp 8000/tcp 8001/tcp 8002/tcp 8080/tcp 8010/tcp                                                                                         8011/tcp 8013/tcp
  protocols:
  source-ports:
  modules:
  destination:

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved and now I enterded DHF quick start.
Authentication setting in port 8000 had been changed to "basic" and it caused the problem.
Changed to "digest" as same as default value and tried logged in via browser, then it worked.Thank you.